# error in socketcan-demo

Tags: ros, can

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand and implement CAN INTERFACES . For this, i found the following link which includes some good socketcan examples. https://github.com/JCube001/socketcan-demo

Though everything was ok till i did "catkin_make' but the rosrun is showing the error of "package not found".
I did the "source devel/setup.bash" which also did not give any error.
So, why the rosrun is not able to be implemented?
The only warning is that when i did catkin_make , i get the a small warning in the beginning as follows:
warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.

I don't know whether this is restricting the rosrun to be executed or not. and where is teh mistake which is failing the rosrun command.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254868/error-in-socketcan-demo/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This github repository does not contain catkin packages, so just `make`..

If you want to integrate it with ROS you can use `socketcan_bridge`, general SocketCAN hints can be found in the wiki: http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-02-17**:
plz confirm whether i understood it right or not'
Need to create a basic catkin package and then perform "git clone" within the package.Similar to the first issue of http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920024736
Same issue is coming at https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen